# can someone explain what i did wrong here? (btc transaction with fee not confirming)

Tags: transaction-fees, confirmations, zero-confirmation

https://blockchain.info/tx/c782b48bba09dea21896b7c58292abaec81d7ce2db2975f30b77176dddad492c

was the fee not high enough? i have never had an issue with fees using the recommended amount that bitcoin core suggests before but now this one, for some reason is just sitting there unconfirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the fee is too low.

The fee (the difference between the input amount and output amount) is only 0.00001329 BTC - about an order of magnitude too low at the time of writing.

Most modern wallet software should propose sensible fees by default. Bitcoin Core started calculating fees dynamically in release 0.10. Could you perhaps be using an old version?

Alternatively, this service can be used to estimate required fees: https://bitcoinfees.21.co

Comment: thanks for replying. im using v0.10.2 so next time ill just ignore the recommended and use that link. so im assuming there is nothing i can do now but wait for someone to process it and do it properly next time? and is there any way to know how long it will take?

Comment: @whiskyjack: Version 0.11.0 fixed some fee estimation behavior, and 0.12.0 made "various improvements to how the wallet calculates transaction fees". I wouldn't be surprised if you had a better user experience after upgrading to a recent version.